# Embedded Resources with cultural suffix in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, embedded-resource

I want to set `Build Action` of two files to `Embedded resource` in an ASP.NET Core 3 project.

```
FileName.json
FileName.en-GB.json
```

But when I try to get embedded resources, there is only one file (first one, without culture suffix)

```
Namespace.Folder.FileName.json
```

At first, I guessed that maybe I have to add second file directly in `.csproj` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\**\*.json" />
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\FileName.en-GB.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But it throws an error:

> Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' items were included

which means it has already been added.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your goal to copy both files to bin at build? If you do this, both files will be copied to bin folder.

      <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\*.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>
      </ItemGroup>

Comment: @JitendraRathor I don't want to copy files to bin folder. I want to add them to embedded sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ItemGroup>
     <!-- This line includes all .json files in Folder and it's subfolders-->
     <EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\**\*.json" />
     <!-- This line is not needed because all .json files are already included -->
     <EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\FileName.en-GB.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So change it to

```
<ItemGroup>
     <!-- This line includes all .json files in Folder and it's subfolders-->
     <EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\**\*.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that FileName.en-GB.json will be included in a satellite assembly not in the main output assembly.

Comment: Generally no, it is not needed. But it depends on the remaining content of the csproj file.

Comment: @SherifElmetainy "satellite assembly" is the key. thank you so much.